# If I want to list multiple variables in one 'if' command in unix, how would I do it? [Beginner]

Tags: unix, if-statement, sh

so I have a really basic question here which I'm sure any experienced user can answer quickly! I'm just not too sure what to search to find the answer!

So lets say I was write an 'if' command in a shellscript and I wanted to essentially say:

```
If test variableA AND variableB AND variableC AND variableD -eq 1 ; then
echo "Bye bye"
fi
```

so basically I'm not sure what to replace the AND's with in UNIX? Do I just write variableA, variableB, variableC, variableD or do I have to list them out in brackets or do I just leave spaces infront of them?

Thanks in advance!

(Also as a bonus question, what if I want to replace the AND with the OR in the example above? How would that translate in UNIX?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-a` is the `AND` operator in `test`:

```
if [ -n "$variableA" -a -n "$variableB" -a -n "$variableC" -a "$variableD" -eq 1 ]
then
    echo "Bye bye"
fi
```

If you want `OR`, the operator is `-o`. These are both in the `test` [man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?test).

Comment: It's a more explicit way of checking whether the variable is nonempty than just putting the variable by itself. It works better if the value might begin with `-`, so it looks like an option.

Comment: Perfect! - Thanks for the answer, I owe you one! I'll tick it once the 5 mins are up! (also, if you have the time, is there an equivalent for OR?)